# Opencart A non-numeric value encountered line number 141

Tags: opencart

Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in

> D:\xampp\htdocs\opencart\admin\model\localisation\currency.php on line
> 141Warning: Division by zero in
> D:\xampp\htdocs\opencart\admin\model\localisation\currency.php on line
> 141Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in
> D:\xampp\htdocs\opencart\admin\model\localisation\currency.php on line
> 141Warning: Division by zero in
> D:\xampp\htdocs\opencart\admin\model\localisation\currency.php on line
> number 141

Comment: What is openc cart version?

Answer (score 2):

yourfoldername\admin\model\localisation\currency.php onpen this file and go to line number 140 and change this

```
if ((float)$value < 1 && isset($line[$i + 1])) {
```

to

```
if ((float)$value < 1 && isset($line[$i + 1]) && is_numeric(($line[$i + 1]))) {
```